# How to decode multi records with Json in java

Tags: java, json

JSON-Simple Example

```
private static String jsonText = "{\"first\": \"ali\", \"second\":" +
                " [4, 5, 6], \"third\": 789},{\"first\": \"saeed\", \"second\":" +
                " [10, 7, 8], \"third\": 1000},{\"first\": \"reza\", \"second\":" +
                " [14, 15, 16], \"third\": 999}";

public static void main(String args[]) 
            throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
        public List creatArrayContainer() {
            return new LinkedList();
        }

        public Map createObjectContainer() {
            return new LinkedHashMap();
        }
    };

    try {
        Map json = (Map)parser.parse(jsonText, containerFactory);
        Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("==iterate result==");
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("==toJSONString()==");
        System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(json));
    } catch(ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println(pe);
    }
}
```

This throw a exception

`Unexpected token COMMA(,) at position 51.`

The `jsonText` is the contents of three records.How can I read three records?

Comment: Have you tried combining them into one? Could that be a possibility or do they need to be separate?

Comment: [That is **not** valid JSON](http://jsonlint.org). Put the elements in an array or otherwise pass your parser valid JSON.

Comment: could you show me with sample?(array sample)

Comment: Your basic problem is that the outermost JSON "layer" wants to be an array (since it's a list of JSON "objects" separated by commas), but you're missing the enclosing `[]` characters around the entire string.

Comment: (I don't think this question necessarily shows "minimal understanding" -- I had to study the string for several minutes to see what was wrong.)

Comment: Saeed -- Go to json.org and study the syntax there.  It's really simple once you get to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't valid. I use jsonlint.com to check json when I'm messing with stuff like this.
Here is an example of some valid JSON (note I removed the backslashes)

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "first": "ali",
            "second": [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ],
            "third": 789
        },
        {
            "first": "saeed",
            "second": [
                10,
                7,
                8
            ],
            "third": 1000
        },
        {
            "first": "reza",
            "second": [
                14,
                15,
                16
            ],
            "third": 999
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @SaeedHassanpour - Go to json.org.  The syntax is quite simple and takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to decode it is to use jackson.
the code I give is written by groovy,but you can easily convert

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    def s="""
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "first": "ali",
                "second": [
                    4,
                    5,
                    6
                ],
                "third": 789
            },
            {
                "first": "saeed",
                "second": [
                    10,
                    7,
                    8
                ],
                "third": 1000
            },
            {
                "first": "reza",
                "second": [
                    14,
                    15,
                    16
                ],
                "third": 999
            }
        ]
    }
    """

    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    def map=mapper.readValue(s,Map.class);
    println map
```

result:

```
 [items:[[first:ali, second:[4, 5, 6], third:789], [first:saeed, second:[10, 7, 8], third:1000], [first:reza, second:[14, 15, 16], third:999]]]
```

then just get the data like using Map(map is actually a Map object).